How can I make the game Rock, Paper, Scissors move forward between rounds using the DOM in JavaScript?
I am making the game Rock, Paper, Scissors in JavaScript, and I am stuck. The problem is that I can't make a loop work to allow me to play 5 rounds in the game, keep a round counter, and update the score. The game is for practicing DOM manipulation.
In the end, I would expect the program to give me the final score and a message to the user to notify if they have won or lost.
I am sharing my complete code with you.


let humanScore = 0
let computerScore = 0
let rounds = 0;

const getComputerChoice = () => {
  const items = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  const randomItems = items[(Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length))];
  return randomItems;
}

const getHumanChoice = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const rockSelection = document.querySelector("#rock");
    const paperSelection = document.querySelector("#paper");
    const scissorsSelection = document.querySelector("#scissors");

    rockSelection.addEventListener("click", () => {
      rockSelection.setAttribute("class", "animation");
      resolve("rock"), {
        once: true
      };
    });

    paperSelection.addEventListener("click", () => {
      paperSelection.setAttribute("class", "animation");
      resolve("paper"), {
        once: true
      };
    });

    scissorsSelection.addEventListener("click", () => {
      scissorsSelection.setAttribute("class", "animation");
      resolve("scissors"), {
        once: true
      };
    });
  });
}


const playRound = (humanChoice, computerChoice) => {
  const textResponse = document.querySelector("#display");
  const para = document.createElement("p");
  para.classList.add("para");
  para.textContent = "";
  textResponse.appendChild(para);

  if (humanChoice == "rock" && computerChoice == "scissors") {
    para.textContent = `You win! ${humanChoice}  beats ${computerChoice} ✂️`;
    humanScore++;
  } else if (humanChoice == "scissors" && computerChoice == "paper") {
    para.textContent = `You win! ${humanChoice} ✂️ beats ${computerChoice} `;
    humanScore++;
  } else if (humanChoice == "paper" && computerChoice == "rock") {
    para.textContent = `You win! ${humanChoice}  beats ${computerChoice} `;
    humanScore++;
  } else if (humanChoice === computerChoice) {
    para.textContent = `You draw! . The computer choose ${computerChoice} too!`;
  } else {
    para.textContent = `You lose! . The computer choose ${computerChoice}`;
    computerScore++;
  }
}

const playGame = async() => {

  const humanChoice = await getHumanChoice();
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();

  playRound(humanChoice, computerChoice);

  const score = document.querySelector("#score");
  const newPara = document.createElement("p");
  newPara.classList.add("Score");
  newPara.textContent = `ROUND ${rounds}: You ${humanScore},
    The computer: ${computerScore}`;
  score.appendChild(newPara);

  if (rounds < 5) {
    const nextDiv = document.createElement("div");
    const nextRound = document.createElement("button");
    nextDiv.classList.add("nextDiv");
    nextRound.classList.add("button");
    nextRound.textContent = "Next round";
    newPara.appendChild(nextDiv);
    nextDiv.appendChild(nextRound);

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      nextRound.addEventListener("click", () => {
        resolve();
      }, {
        once: true
      });
    });
  }
};

const loopRounds = async() => {
  while (rounds < 5) {
    rounds++;
    await playGame()
  }

  const finalMessage = document.createElement("p");
  if (humanScore > computerScore) {
    finalMessage.textContent = "You are the best!";
  } else if (humanScore < computerScore) {
    finalMessage.textContent = "You are the worst in the world!";
  } else {
    finalMessage.textContent = "It's a draw!"
  }

  document.querySelector("#score").appendChild(finalMessage);

}

loopRounds();
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Piedra Papel y tijera</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    
    #botones {
      display: flex;
      gap: 10px;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100px;
    }
    
    .animation {
      background-color: #5240F5;
    }
    
    #title {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    #subTitle {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    button {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #3FA2F6;
      color: white;
    }
    
    #display {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    #score {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .Score {
      justify-content: center;
      font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    
    .para {
      justify-content: center;
      font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    
    .nextDiv {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="title">
    <h1>✂️Rock, Paper and Scissors ✂️</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="subTitle">
    <h2>Pick an option </h2>
  </div>

  <div id="botones">
    <button id="rock" value="Rock">Rock</button>
    <button id="paper" value="Paper">Paper</button>
    <button id="scissors" value="Scissors">scissors</button>
  </div>

  <div id="display"></div>
  <div id="score"></div>
  <script src="codigo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




The event listeners inside getHumanChoice are wrong setted.
This is how it should be:
rockSelection.addEventListener("click", () => {
  rockSelection.setAttribute("class", "animation");
  resolve("rock")
}, {
  once: true
});

paperSelection.addEventListener("click", () => {
  paperSelection.setAttribute("class", "animation");
  resolve("paper")
}, {
  once: true
});

scissorsSelection.addEventListener("click", () => {
  scissorsSelection.setAttribute("class", "animation");
  resolve("scissors")
}, {
  once: true
});

I would like to add some code review comments:

while loop is totally unnecesary, I will suggest you to call loopRounds at the end of playGame and check the count
move your event listeners to the top level
instead of resolving the promise, call the playGame function and pass the selected choice
remove once property if you have moved your event listeners to the top level, it doesnt make sense to force to execute your event listener only once
remove promises, for your actual code and project, its unnecessary and only over complicates it

Hope this helps you, happy coding
